# Extract an object of names from type properties

Tags: typescript, object, types

I need to create an object with the same properties/values as the properties of a custom type:

```
type MyType = {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
  propC: string;
}

const foo = {
  propA: "propA",
  propB: "propB",
  propC: "propC",
}
```

I can define a type to make the object to require all the prop names such as:

```
const foo: { [key in keyof MyType]: string } = {
  propA: "propA",
  propB: "propB",
  propC: "propC",
};
```

That will require all the properties to exist, but not the values. I need those values to be called the same as the props. Is there a way to define its value with any typescript syntax sugar?? For example, with something like this:

```
const foo: { [key in keyof MyType]: string } = Object.keys(MyType); 
// of course MyType is a type, not an object and this can't work.. but anything like that is what I need
```

Any idea is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to use a generic function to enforce the keys and infer the types:

```
function props<T extends { [key in keyof MyType]: string }>(p: T): T { return p; }

const foo = props({
  propA: "propA",
  propB: "propB",
  propC: "propC",
});
```

But in TypeScript 4.9, we have [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const foo = {
  propA: "propA",
  propB: "propB",
  propC: "propC",
} satisfies { [key in keyof MyType]: string };
```

And on another note, you could just replace `{ [key in keyof MyType]: string }` with `Record<keyof MyType, string>`.

Comment: But instead of infering the type, I want to "infer" or create automatically the object with those names and values (so I don't have to type { propA: "propA", propB: "propB"} etc..). Sounds like i don't want to type haha but what I want is to define a simple way to implement this "in a generic/easy way" to be reused and avoid mistakes.

btw, thanks for the Record<> tip!

Comment: @HansAraya Is an array what you want? Then it would be `(keyof MyType)[]`.